# Significance of import statement inside and outside of an module

Tags: rust

I am very new to Rust and trying my best to understand what is going on.
Directory structure looks like this.

```
├── Cargo.lock
├── Cargo.toml
├── src
│   ├── main.rs
│   ├── models.rs
│   ├── routes.rs
│   └── utils.rs
```

Error is in `routes.rs` file.

```
use crate::models::api_models::Response;
pub mod api_paths {
    pub fn home() -> (String, String) {
        println!("In Home Page");
        return ("HTTP/1.1 200 OK".to_string(), Response {
            code: 200,
            message: String::from("In Home Page"),
        }.to_string())
    }
    pub fn not_found() -> (String, String){
        println!("This path is not implemented");
        return ("HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found".to_string(), Response {
            code: 200,
            message: String::from("404 Not Found"),
        }.to_string())
    }
}
```

Compiler is saying.

```
error[E0422]: cannot find struct, variant or union type `Response` in this scope
 --> src/routes.rs:6:48
  |
6 |         return ("HTTP/1.1 200 OK".to_string(), Response {
  |                                                ^^^^^^^^ not found in this scope
  |
help: consider importing this struct
  |
4 |     use crate::routes::Response;
  |

error[E0422]: cannot find struct, variant or union type `Response` in this scope
  --> src/routes.rs:13:55
   |
13 |         return ("HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found".to_string(), Response {
   |                                                       ^^^^^^^^ not found in this scope
   |
help: consider importing this struct
   |
4  |     use crate::routes::Response;
   |

warning: unused import: `crate::models::api_models::Response`
 --> src/routes.rs:1:5
  |
1 | use crate::models::api_models::Response;
  |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  |
  = note: `#[warn(unused_imports)]` on by default

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0422`.
warning: `web-app` (bin "web-app") generated 1 warning
error: could not compile `web-app` due to 2 previous errors; 1 warning emitted
```

But, if I put the import statement inside the `mod`, then it works just fine.

```
pub mod api_paths {
    // This works!
    use crate::models::api_models::Response;
    pub fn home() -> (String, String) {
        println!("In Home Page");
        return ("HTTP/1.1 200 OK".to_string(), Response {
            code: 200,
            message: String::from("In Home Page"),
        }.to_string())
    }
    pub fn not_found() -> (String, String){
        println!("This path is not implemented");
        return ("HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found".to_string(), Response {
            code: 200,
            message: String::from("404 Not Found"),
        }.to_string())
    }
}
```

My `models.rs` looks like this.

```
use std::{
    fmt
};
pub mod api_models {
    pub struct Response {
        pub code: i16,
        pub message: String,
    }
    
}
impl fmt::Display for api_models::Response {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        write!(
            f,
            "{{\"code\":\"{}\", \"message\":\"{}\"}}",
            self.code, self.message
        )
    }
}
```

I am not able to understand why. Please suggest.

Comment: Simple. Modules do not automatically import anything from their parent module. Any imports used in the module must be in the module.

Comment: You can do `use super::*;` to import everything in the parent module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your full answer is [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch07-00-managing-growing-projects-with-packages-crates-and-modules.html)

but for quick solution if you have a project structure like this

```
- src/main.rs
- src/models.rs
- src/utils.rs
...
```

you must define what modules your project have so for that you just need add the following in main.rs

```
mod models;
mod utils;
```

above code tell compiler what modules you have and remember `main.rs` it's your main module so you must define modules there

if you have lib crate, `lib.rs` will be your main module

now for import data types you have two options

first from root crate like this

```
use crate::models::*; // import every things in models module
```

second from parent or super crate, it's uses when inner module wanna access super module data types

```
use super::*
```

remember `use` keyword must place inside the module

if you have `routes.rs` and then create another module '''api_path``` inside it

`routes` is super module and second one will be inner module and must have another import codes